# Read data from file into Textfields java

Tags: java, textfield

Hello i've got a problem 
I would like to read data from text file, every single data is in diffrent line, it looks like this

```
599
1188
1189
998
1998
2598
2899
3998
998
628
1178
1198
399
385
294
1380
```

I've as much as lines is textfields 
jTextField1, jTextField2...
I'd like to put into these datas... I literally dont know how to deal with it

jTextField1 should have value 599
jTextField2 shoulv have value 1188

No clue how to do it. Can u help me guys please :)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Reading the file? Setting the textfield's text? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how to read and put it into textfields :(

Comment: Go look up some tutoriasl or pay attention in class.

Comment: @Sedrick, im learning on my own, cannot find stuff what can help me

Comment: If you are leaning on your own, then you should be following some book or some tutorial to master the basics. From there you should easily be able to do what you are trying to do. I am guessing you are using `Swing`. If you are and it's purely learning on your own, I would suggest you learn `JavaFX`. You can find many free tutorial and books that can teach you the basics.

Comment: @Sedrick So show me the tutorial where i can find way to fill textfields with data from file in the case as i'm looking for

Comment: I gave the advice I am going to give. Maybe someone will come along and give you want you want. Seems like you are trying to get HW done to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line-by-line using FileReader/BufferedReader or Scanner:

```
String filename = "path/to/the/file/with/numbers.txt";
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
    String line;
    int currentIndex = 1;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // see further on how to implement the below method
        setTextFieldValue(currentIndex, line.trim());
        currentIndex++
    }
}
```

To implement setTextFieldValue, you have a couple of options:

1. write a switch case to map the index to the corresponding field
2. make a map of index -> field, or an array (as suggested by @zlakad in the comments)
3. Use reflection to get fields by their names

All of the above options have their pros and cons which depends on the context. Below I'll show how to implement it using reflection, because the other two options are quite straightforward:

```
void setTextFieldValue(int index, String value) {
    // assuming the fields belong to the same class as this method
    Class klass = this.getClass(); 
    try {
        Field field = klass.getField("jTextField" + index);
        JTextField text = (JTextField)field.get(this);
        text.setText(value);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // throw it further, or wrap it into appropriate exception type
        // or just and swallow it, based on your use-case.
        // You can throw a custom checked exception
        // and catch in the caller method to stop the processing 
        // once you encounter index that has no corresponding field
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe u are able to some live help?

Comment: Good answer. However, I think there is another (4th) way do implement `setTextFieldValue` - initialize an array of `JTextField` like `JTextField[] jTextFields = new JTextField[NO_OF_DATA]`, and place that into the parent container.

Comment: @GGrela SO is not a code writing service, if my answer is not enough for you to start doing something yourself you should go seek help somewhere else.